# Halley comet flyby

Tags: orbital-maneuver, gravity, comet

Halley's comet's next perihelion will happen around mid 2061.

Considering, that its orbit is retrograde (viewable [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=1P;orb=1)), is it possible to build a  flyby trajectory by means of **gravitational maneuvers** around the planets and moons?

Comment: Flybys (not rendezvous) from the last visit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley_Armada

Comment: There's some info on where Haley's comet is now in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29662/7982). Telescopes have gotten so big now that it can always be imaged!

Comment: Two flyby rules of thumb:
1. If you can reach Jupiter, you can go anywhere.
2. Add together the orbital period of the planets you plan on using to see if it's feasible.
Earth + Venus + Jupiter fits with a very roomy margin, and should give a vast space of opportunities. You can even fit two Jupiter flybys in there.

Comment: If Halley's orbit and Jupiters don't come close to intersecting (basically if Halley's does not cross the ecliptic somewhere near Jupiter's distance from the Sun) things get a lot harder.

Comment: @Hohmannfan: #1 makes sense. Could you explain #2? What does adding orbital periods have to do with feasibility?

Comment: @Paul it comes from that the fact that these trajectories takes years to execute, roughly proportional to the orbital periods of the objects involved. It's further cemented by the the proper alignments also arriving at similar time spans.

Comment: A couple of things that could be clarified: (1) What initial launch impulse is allowed? You can't get off Earth, or out of LEO just using gravitational maneuvers. (2) are you allowing flybys at any relative velocity (so the probe might only spend a few seconds really close to the comet), or are you looking for something closer to a rendezvous?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based upon what was done for the last time Halley's comet came by.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suisei_(spacecraft)

Fifteen burns of Suisei's 3 N motors during the period of April 5–10, 1987, yielded a 65 m/s velocity increase for a 60,000 km Earth gravity assist swingby on August 20, 1992, helped it establish a Heliocentric orbit around the sun.

Also see Halley Armada
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley_Armada

Comment: Thanks. But this is not an answer unfortunately

Comment: @Leeloo: Since Halley crosses Earth's orbit, it is fairly easy to do a flyby, but the relative velocity will be quite high because it's retrograde. If you want to match velocity, then it's difficult, and may or may not be feasible.

Comment: @Leeloo: How is this not an answer? The answer states: "This has done before, so we can do it again." Pretty clear to me.